# Difference between RLMRealm and Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Very new to Realm and am wanting to start off right. I see a lot of examples using `RLMRealm` and companion `RLMRealmConfiguration` and in general a lot of `RLM*` things. On some Swift examples I also am seeing a just plain `Realm` and `Realm.Configuration` and other things without the `RLM` prefix. It appears this is the `RealmSwift` way?

There is no mention of the name change between versions or a naming transition. Both work with Swift. I have found the things without the prefix are far less feature complete than their `RLM` counterparts.

Looking at the source it appears the non-prefixed versions are wrappers?

I'm using Swift. I'd like to stay with the "preferred" way but don't know which that is. Which do I choose: `RLMRealm` or `Realm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pure Objective-C classes contain the prefix, the pure Swift classes do not.

Depending on the language of your project, you will use either the Objective-C or the Swift implementation of Realm.

You can see all of the classes (both Objective-C and Swift) in the [Realm-Cocoa repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa).

Comment: I see Objective C code beneath RealmSwift. Is RealmSwift really pure swift? It's working on top of Objective C, right? Is there any advantage in migrating my models written in Swift using Realm to the RealmSwift version?